# Want to change color of a grid on second click

Tags: java, android, gridview, calendar, onclicklistener

I have created a custom calendar, in which i'm setting the color for a single grid when it is clicked. My requirement is to change the color to some other color on second click. I tried achieving this by placing a onclick listener inside another onclick listener. It worked but its very buggy. sometimes the 2nd color stays in the previous grid or sometimes it doesnt work and sometimes it 'll turn to second color when i click on a previously clicked grid.

My requirement is to change the color of a grid to color1 on 1st click and color2 on second click on same grid cell.

Answer (score 1):

try using counter for `onClick`. and according to counter change the color of grid..
set initially 0, if clicked once set it to 1 change the color and if clicked again increase counter and change color again. don't use onclick inside onclick.

Comment: but if i maintain a counter, that counter wont apply for each cell independently right? once i increase the counter to 1, my code will interpret clicking on any other cell as a 2nd click and it'd change the cell color to color2 on 1st click of any other cell. Thats not what i want.

My req. are:
1. Change to color1 on 1st click on a cell.
2. Change to 2nd color on 2nd click on the same cell.
3. If 1st click on an other cell after step 1, then reset the color of the cell i clicked in step 1 and change the color of the cell i clicked now to color 1.

Comment: @user2362126: you are going to add onClick on item and not on total list at a time. so you have to maintain a click on each view. so if you are using multiple cells setTag() and getTag() so that you will get a particular view. set onClick on View.

Answer (score 0):

use index counter and in onClick listener update the counter and change the color.

Comment: Your suggestion might have worked if i had only one cell/item to change. But i have 30 cells. Each has to change on its own. If i change counter to 1 for a click on one cell, then the code woud interpret 1st click on any other cell as 2nd click s the counter is 1 now. Thats not what i want. I have specified my req. in Mahaveer Muttha's comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for

`GestureDetector`

you can find more of it here - [Detecting Common Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

with this you can detect common gestures like touch, down, fling, single tap, double tap, long press scroll

Comment: I went through the link you suggested, I wonder whether double tap means a consecutive 2 clicks done quickly or just two clicks. If its just two clicks then it might solve my problem. But i really doubt it though.

Comment: what difference `a consecutive 2 clicks done quickly or just two clicks` make?...can you explain what exactly your are looking for?...I might have misunderstood your question.. :|

Comment: sure. there are 30 cells in color0. when i click on a single cell, the color of that cell changes to color1. when if i click the same cell again, it should change to color2. If after clicking on a cell once, if i click on any other cell, the previous cell should go back to color0 and the clicked cell should change to color1.

How do i do this?

Comment: this will be much easier. when user clicks om the cell get the color of that cell and according to the color it is currently having just change the color to next respective color. like 
`if color0 then go to color1 and if color1 go to color2 and if color2 go to color0`

Comment: yes, thats what i wanted...i have thought about it...but can u just give me a sample code how to get the color of the cell?